# Xamarin Forms: How to show Framelayout one top of another?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a design like below. The left part is upcoming events and the right part is all events.

When clicking the upcoming events I need to show the layout of the upcoming event fully including the rounded corners and it should be on the top of all event layout(top section of the screenshot). When clicking all events I need to show the all event layout fully including it's rounded corners(bottom section). Please see the following screenshot:

[image]

I am using `Framelayout` for this design and see my codes below:

```
<StackLayout
      Orientation="Horizontal"
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

       <Frame
              x:Name="Upcoming_layout"
              Padding="8"
              Margin="8,0,0,0"
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              CornerRadius="20"
              BackgroundColor="#0091da">

          <Label 
               x:Name="Upcoming_label"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               Text="Upcoming Events"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="18"
               TextColor="#FFFFFF"/>
         </Frame>

           <Frame
                  x:Name="All_layout"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  CornerRadius="20"
                  Margin="-35,0,8,0"
                  Padding="8"
                  BackgroundColor="#28b0f4">

              <Label 
                   Text="All Events"
                   x:Name="allevents_label"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   FontSize="18"
                   TextColor="#aee4ff"/>
           </Frame>
     </StackLayout>
```

I have added some negative margin for the second frame and the second layout is always on top of the first layout. See the screenshot below:

[image]

When tapping the first layout I need it on top, and when tapping all events it should show on top. Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **RaiseChild**

```
YourStackLayout.RaiseChild(Upcoming_layout)
```

Comment: What is `View` in this?

Comment: @SreejithSree i'm sorry, i made a mistake, i edited my anwser, is it more clear?

Comment: One last question, I added above code on the onclik event and it is working fine when tapping layouts. But when the initial loading it shows the second layout on top, how I can show the first layout on top when loaing initailly

Comment: I tried to add `YourStackLayout.RaiseChild(Upcoming_layout)` inside of the constructor, but it collapses the design and showing All events on first and Upcoming event on second.

Comment: try to do it on the override method OnAppearing

Comment: Tried adding there also, but same result

Comment: then you can try to change the order of the layouts, and then, add "HorizontalOptions:StartAndExpand" on the layout you want to be the at the left, and "HorizontalOptions:EndAndExpand" on the layout on the right

Comment: I have added negative layout for my second layout`(Margin="-35,0,8,0")` that's why initially the second layout coming on top. Is there any way to show the layout one top of another without using the negative margin?